# How to use Mono to script with C# in a Game Environment

Tags: c#, c++, .net, scripting, mono

In short, how does one implement scripting for a game with Mono?

Is the idea that you compile all the scripts into an assembly and then load it and run the scripts from this one assembly. If so, how does one switch assembly after running the compilation one.

I currently have an assembly that is loaded and run at the init stage of the Engine. It opens an assembly which compiles all the scripts in the "Scripts/" directory. This then compiles them all into a new assembly called "Scripts.dll". My problem, is how to access this new assembly and be able to call an init/update/render function from the Engine.

Currently, I do this:

```
bool ScriptingEngine::Init()
{
std::cout << " " << std::endl;  

mono_set_dirs(PathUtil::GetLibDirectory().c_str(), PathUtil::GetConfigDirectory().c_str());

domain = mono_jit_init ("System");
assembly = mono_domain_assembly_open (domain, "../build/Resources/Scripts/2.0/ScriptLoader.exe");
if (!assembly)
{
    std::cout << "SCRIPTING FAILED" << std::endl;
    return false;
}
image = mono_assembly_get_image(assembly); 

mono_jit_exec(domain, assembly, argc, argv);
ScriptingClass class1 = scripting_createClass("ScriptManager", "ScriptLoader");
scripting_call(class1, "LoadScripts");

std::cout << " " << std::endl;  
return true;

}
```

Now, to access this new assembly. How would I do this? I see nothing about loading multiple assemblies in the documentation or support of Mono. I need to load the assembly and be able to call a function from any of the scripts. Is this even the right way to do it?